# GMPY2 install: DLL load failed: %1 is not a valid Win32 application

Tags: python, gmpy

I tried to install gmpy2 on my python distribution (Anaconda 64bit) and I did this by downloading the precompiled .PYD file from http://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs and put the file in the site-packages folder (I tried this with both the 32 bit and 64 bit versions). However when I ran it and tried to import gmpy2 it gave the following error: DLL load failed: %1 is not a valid Win32 application. I do not know how to fix this as everything I am using is 64 bit. I have looked at some of the other answers on this site but none of them seem to help. Does anyone know what I might try to do?

Comment: I am assuming you are using Python-2.7,  you will need to match both the Python version and the archtype (x86 v x64).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After downloading the [GMPY wheel file from Christoph Gohlke's site](http://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/#gmpy), you need to open a command window and change to the folder where you downloaded GMPY, and use [pip](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/pip) to install it:

```
~\Downloads\> pip install gmpy2‑2.0.5‑cp27‑none‑win_amd64.whl
```

If you don't have pip, use [conda](http://conda.pydata.org/) to install it first:

```
~> conda install setuptools pip
```

*Note:* I used the tilde to represent `C:\Users\<username>\`.